# SpringBoot, limit request size of a PUT request

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I'm running a spring-boot service with an embed tomcat container.

Is there a way to limit the size of a HTTP **PUT** request via common application properties or EmbeddedServletContainerFactory? 
Thanks

Comment: I am not even sure that tomcat has such feature. It has for POST which I am sure you're aware since you specified PUT in bold. If tomcat has this feature then yes you can customize that via `org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer`

Comment: maybe unrelated but there is `multipart.maxFileSize` property

Comment: @sodik the multipart properties are considered only for multipart data requests, I tested it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: yes, I know - that's why I said `maybe unrelated` - but maybe it can help in someone's situation.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, do you have any answer now?

Answer (score 1):

Add this property in your application.properties file.

```
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
```

Refer below for more information:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html